# Unwrapping a Markdown table with a Pandoc Lua filter

Tags: lua, markdown, pandoc

I have a DOCX file with this content:

```
# Heading

+---------------------+
| Paragraph           |
|                     |
| ## Subheading       |
|                     |
| +-----------------+ |
| | Nested table    | |
| +-----------------+ |
+---------------------+

One last paragraph
```

[Here is a sample file.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9b5ynke5zbm1j1y/tables.docx?dl=1)

I want to run it through Pandoc and get this Markdown, with all tables unwrapped:

```
# Heading

Paragraph      

## Subheading  

Nested table 

One last paragraph
```

I'm trying to write a Lua filter with [walk_block](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#pandoc.walk_block) but I have no experience with Lua and not making any progress. Can anyone point me in a helpful direction?

```
function Table(table)
    pandoc.walk_block(table, {
        Str = function(el)
            -- TODO now what???
        end
    })
end
```

Comment: Please attach a sample docx file for us to test with.

Comment: No problem, just edited to add: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9b5ynke5zbm1j1y/tables.docx?dl=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lua interface to tables is currently rather complex, so it's much simpler to convert the table into a so-called *simple table*. We can do so with `pandoc.utils.to_simple_table`. A *simple table* has a header row (`header`) and multiple body rows (`rows`), and we get access to cells by iterating over a row. Each cell is just a `Blocks` list, which we can collect in an accumulator.

Here's how this looks like:

```lua
function Table (tbl)
  local simpleTable = pandoc.utils.to_simple_table(tbl)
  local blocks = pandoc.Blocks{}
  for _, headercell in ipairs(simpleTable.header) do
    blocks:extend(headercell)
  end
  for _, row in ipairs(simpleTable.rows) do
    for _, cell in ipairs(row) do
      blocks:extend(cell)
    end
  end
  return blocks, false
end
```

Running that filter should unwrap all tables, leaving just their contents.